# Is what I see going on here, really going on here?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I admin a couple pages on FB and we recently got hit by a supposedly fake page.

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Duke-St-Rollins/478408292178951

The page is supposedly a duplicate of this user:

http://www.facebook.com/DukeStRollins

However. When I entered this into `Graph.facebook.com/478408292178951` I got this returned:

```
{
   "name": "Duke St. Rollins",
   "is_published": true,
   "talking_about_count": 2,
   "category": "Public figure",
   "id": "478408292178951",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Duke-St-Rollins/478408292178951",
   "likes": 2
}
```

When I entered THIS into `graph.facebook.com/Duke-St-Rollins` I got this returned:

```
{
   "name": "Duke St. Rollins",
   "is_published": true,
   "username": "DukeStRollins",
   "about": "World famous troll and nemesis of teabaggers.",
   "bio": "Press!\n\nhttp://blogs.phoenixnewtimes.com/bastard/2012/07/duke_st_rollins_on_jan_brewer.php \n\nhttp://madmikesamerica.com/2012/07/an-interview-with-duke-st-rollins/\n\nYouTube Channel\nhttp://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_xk6GQzKacHImYl3Vns4VQ\n",
   "personal_info": "Follow me on Twitter  ",
   "talking_about_count": 6450,
   "category": "Public figure",
   "id": "204170076355643",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/DukeStRollins",
   "likes": 9459,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": 261500633955920,
      "source": "http://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s720x720/376513_261500633955920_779910133_n.jpg",
      "offset_y": 92
   }
}
```

If I am understanding how this works correctly, and did this right, does this mean the supposed 'fake' FB page is actually owned by the 'real' Duke?

If I have this wrong (and I hope I do), can someone please explain this to me slowly, like you are talking to a kid as I am TOTALLY new to doing the FB page stuff and until yesterday, never even knew about `graph.facebook` stuff.

Consider me a noob. Because I am. But I'd really like to know if what I think I am seeing, is what I fear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they aren't the same. The former is a page/public figure. The latter is a user. You can tell them apart by their different IDs (478408292178951 / 204170076355643). They share the same name but can't share the same graph api address because hyphens are ignored (try http://graph.facebook.com/Duke-------------StRollins), which means DukeStRollins and Duke-St-Rollins are effectively identical.

This is in my opinion a glitch in the API: a query by name should be able to distinguish between these two resources, even if a hyphen - is the only difference between their names; that there is not just makes it easier for the spoofer to confuse people.

You've probably already seen this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I'm not sure I undersand the 'glitch' here - one is a page whose URL is **http://www.facebook.com/pages/Duke-St-Rollins/478408292178951** and the other is a page whose url is **http://www.facebook.com/DukeStRollins**

Comment: What feels like a glitch is that the - hyphen character is ignored by the API, even though, as this case demonstrates, it may be the only difference between the name of two graph objects (one, as you say, a user, and the other a page). It's bizarre that to the API, http://graph.facebook.com/Duke---S--t-R-ollins == http://graph.facebook.com/DukeStRollins, and in this case it makes it impossible to distinguish between two REST resources which ought both to be queryable by name. I accept that calling this a glitch is my opinion though, and I've edited my answer above to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you. I have just started getting into this and when I saw that I was really worried someone I got a lot of enjoyment from reading the stuff he puts out was also going to pages and putting really really offensive pictures up. I hoped I was wrong and just not understanding how the api worked, and it seems my hope has been realized. 

Now I have to start learning this stuff from top to bottom. I appreciate the answer and the help. Thank you.

Comment: @Samuel J Selby You are welcome. Please mark this as the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

In http://www.facebook.com/pages/Duke-St-Rollins/478408292178951 "Duke-St-Rollins" is just a dummy name created by the Facebook using the title name of the page. You can use anything in place of it to redirect you to the same page. The below links will all redirect you to http://www.facebook.com/pages/Duke-St-Rollins/478408292178951

1. http://www.facebook.com/pages/page-name/478408292178951
2. http://www.facebook.com/pages/page-title-name/478408292178951
3. http://www.facebook.com/pages/dummy-name/478408292178951
4. http://www.facebook.com/478408292178951 (note that here facebook recognizes 478408292178951 as the username for the page since the page didn't set it's username yet)

In the other page, http://www.facebook.com/Duke-St-Rollins  "Duke-St-Rollins" is a username set by the page and hence it uses "dukestrollins" as the facebook graph node to recognize the page. (Note that in the username any dots or hypens will be removed automatically) All the links below redirect you to http://www.facebook.com/DukeStRollins

1. http://www.facebook.com/duke.st.rollins
2. http://www.facebook.com/dukestrollins
3. http://www.facebook.com/Duke-StRollins
4. http://www.facebook.com/204170076355643
5. http://www.facebook.com/pages/some-thing-here/204170076355643